# QtCreator does not run qmake automatically when adding class

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake, nmake

I'm using QtCreator 3.4.2 (Opensource) with Visual studio 2013 kit on Windows7 64 bit. and I'm using Qt 5.5.

In a project, when I add a class by right-clicking on project and selecting `Add New...->C++ Class`, qmake does not run automatically, and I must call it manually with the Build menu.

How can I configure QtCreator so qmake is called automatically every time is needed?

Comment: OK, I see the problem now. It works with Qt 4, but not with Qt 5, and this is a bug but I don't know whether a Qt Creator bug or Qt bug.

Comment: Is there a place where Qt creator logs are stored, in order to check if something goes wrong?

Comment: Nothing goes wrong. Note that the "Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step" is a red herring. It is always shown no matter what. It is shown when compiling with Qt 4, where things work.

Comment: Maybe is a qtcreator bug. because it should call qmake when needed. If I call qmake then project is update correcly.

Comment: I can confirm that this is **NOT** a Qt Creator bug. Qt Creator has no business calling qmake when a `Makefile` exists. The `Makefile` itself invokes `qmake` when the `.pro` file is newer than the `Makefile`, thus regenerating the `Makefile`. There seems to be a `qmake` bug in Qt 5's qmake - it generates a Makefile that somehow doesn't do its job.

Comment: Ok I understand. I didn't know this feature of the makefile. Then I'll perform some other test and then I'll report it. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Again, please forget about Qt Creator in all of this. Qt Creator's logic is as follows: Makefile doesn't exist? Run qmake. Finally, run jom or nmake. That's it. Whenever the `.pro` file is changed, `jom` or `nmake` are supposed to regenerate the makefile. You can reproduce your issue from the command line by invoking `jom` or `nmake` from the build folder - as you would if you manually built the project.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to invoke it manually, the make tool will do it for you (either `nmake` or `jom`, depending on what you use - and you should be using `jom` of course). I will simply refer to the make tool as `nmake`, though.

The `Makefile` generated for `nmake` has the `Makefile` itself dependent on the `.pro` file. Whenever you build the project, `nmake` will act on this dependency, `qmake` will run, and the `Makefile` will get regenerated and reloaded by `nmake`, thus taking into account any changes to the `.pro` file.

This is taken care of by `qmake` and `nmake` themselves, Qt Creator doesn't have to do anything here to make it happen.

To test, <kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd> to build the project, ensure that the *Compile Output* window is nominal and the build succeeds. Then add a space to the very beginning of the `.pro` file, and hit <kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd> again. The compile output should show that `qmake` was invoked to regenerate the `Makefile`, and no other files get recompiled (correctly, in this case).

Comment: Actually, I think @Jepessen's problem is that qmake does *not* run (properly) when pressing Ctrl-B.  In my case, when I update and save the .pro file and press Ctrl-B in Qt Creator (3.4.2), the compile output shows "Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step."  So the question remains, how do I tell Qt Creator to *not* to skip the qmake step when the .pro file is updated.

Comment: Indeed. When I add a class by right-clicking on the project->Add New->Class, I must re-run manually the qmake because that class is added in the qmakefile but qmake is not called and I must do it manually.

Comment: Actually, while it is reported that the "qmake step" is skipped, it does run and produce a new Makefile in my case (looking at the time stamps).  However, since the source code wasn't updated, (n)make isn't executed and the code itself isn't rebuilt using that new Makefile.  If I update the .pro file *and* a source file, everything works.  In principle, make builds anything that is older than its source - IMHO it should rebuild all if the Makefile is newer...

Comment: @AstroFloyd The "Configuration unchanged" message is from Creator and is irrelevant. The makefile contains a dependency from `foo.pro` to `Makefile`. It will regenerate the `Makefile` as needed.

Comment: @AstroFloyd The "it does run and produce a new Makefile" action is done by make, not by Qt Creator. When you build a project in Qt Creator, make is **always** executed. If the changes to the makefile are such that the output depends on newer source files, your output will be rebuilt.

Comment: @AstroFloyd If you have added files *older* than the output, then unfortunately nothing will be done. But I have not seen any situation when adding *newer* sources to the `.pro` file doesn't regenerate the output executable. To reproduce such a situation, you'd need a script that generates relevant files in proper order and shows that it does happen. So far, I haven't seen it happen.

Comment: @Jeppesen Perhaps on your platform, somehow, the Makefile doesn't depend on the input .pro file. Please inspect the Makefile to check which is the case. Nominally, qmake generates a `foo.pro -> Makefile` dependency, and the make tool is supposed to act on that. If it doesn't, it's a make bug..

Comment: I'm using the Visual studio toolset so qmake generates a project file that is compiled with nmake or equivalent, I suppose. The problem is that the .proj is not updated when I add a class in the project using QtCreator. but If then I run qmake manually the class is correctly added and compiled.

Comment: @Jeppesen `.proj`? Did you mean `.pro`? `qmake` generates, literally, a file called `Makefile`! When you add files in Qt Creator, the changes are immediately made to the `.pro` (not `.proj`) file. As soon as you build the project, the changes are propagated from `.pro` to `Makefile`. There's no `.proj`. Please check your build directory for the `Makefile`, and inspect it to confirm or deny the presence of the `Makefile: foo.pro` dependency. if such dependency is present, your `nmake` is somehow buggy. No matter what toolset you use, all `qmake` does is take `.pro` and generate `Makefile`.